# select a part of a innertext of an element through mouse cursor / keyboard action / Action class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

how to select specific word (in this case "into force") from a inner text of an element using mouse cursor  / keyboard actions / Actions class.

I am using Selenium(3.141.59) + Java (1.8) + Cucumber Framework + Selenium Grid (4)

Could you please me on this.

Thanks and Regards
Satyabrata

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pytUm.png

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: You can use the xPath `"text()"` method to find specific text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Select partial text with JavaScriptExecutor

This is pure JavaScript example of how to select some text.
`start`, `end` are start and end coordinates of the text selection range.

```
function selectText(element, start, end) {
    selection = window.getSelection();        
    range = new Range();
    range.setStart(element.childNodes[0], start);
    range.setEnd(element.childNodes[0], end);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
}

selectText(document.querySelector("#PageContent > h2:nth-child(7)"), 5, 20);
```

And this should be executed with WebDriver:

```
String jsScript = "function selectText(element, start, end) {\n" +
        "    selection = window.getSelection();        \n" +
        "    range = new Range();\n" +
        "    range.setStart(element.childNodes[0], start);\n" +
        "    range.setEnd(element.childNodes[0], end);\n" +
        "    selection.removeAllRanges();\n" +
        "    selection.addRange(range);\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "\n" +
        "selectText(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]);";

WebElement someElementWithText = driver.findElement(...);
int start = 5;
int end = 20;
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(jsScript, someElementWithText, start, end)
```

This will select a partial text from letter 5 to letter 20.

If you like to select the text from *some start text*, and which ends with *some end text*:

```
String fullText = someElementWithText.getText();
int start = fullText.indexOf("some start text");
int end = fullText.lastIndexOf("some end text") + "some end text".length();
```

#### Select partial text with WebDriver Actions

This might be solved with Actions chain, but coordinates for mouse movements should be defined experimentally. And it highly depends on the element width, browser window width, so it's not very stable.

But in general, this will work:

Just `x1` and `x2` should be defined based on your requirements.

`x=0, y=0` - is the element center.

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html");

Thread.sleep(3000);

WebElement textContainer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[2]"));
int x1 = ...;
int x2 = ...;
new Actions(driver)
        .moveToElement(textContainer, x1, 0)
        .clickAndHold()
        .moveToElement(textContainer, x2, 0)
        .release()
        .build().perform();
```

[image]

You might try to make this more flexible, while getting the element with programatically:

```
int width = textContainer.getSize().getWidth();
```

and trying to define `x1`, `x2` relatively to the element width, like:

```
int x1 = -4*(width/10); // take 40% (of the full width) to the left from elements center
int x2 = -5*(width/100); // take 5% to the left from elements center
```

Comment: I have tried this approach it is working but i need to select a specific visible text of an element? Is that doable?

Comment: @SatyabrataDas I've added one more option - with JavaScriptExecutor.

Comment: Thanks. its working now with JavaScriptExecutor solution....